# How to reference named table or code block in Org-mode

Tags: org-mode, hyperlinks

In Org-mode buffers, table or code block can have `#+NAME: title`.
But I don't know how to reference them in current buffer or in other files with org-mode hyperlink. (like one link format: `[[file:some-file.org::*headline]]`)

Org-mode has support for some [Custom Search](http://orgmode.org/org.html#Custom-searches) functions.
By default, Org-mode does not supprt this.

Does anybody knows how to add this support?

Comment: Can you make your question more clear? Provide an example text with the expected behaviour, and your research so far; with links to these "custom search" facilities in org mode.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found the solution, Org-mode radio target can be used here.
here is the doc: http://orgmode.org/org.html#Internal-links
Like this:

```
Here is a named table.

#+NAME: my target
| x | y |
| 1 | 2 |

I can reference it with its name. Like this:
[[my target]]
```

There are also [table remote references](http://orgmode.org/manual/References.html#index-remote-references-352) further explained by an example in the following.

First we define a table with a name `TBL_origin` to have something to play with.
The two numbers in the row `Average` are referenced in the tables further below.

```
  #+NAME: TBL_origin
  | Leaders  | Caption 1 | Caption 2 |
  |----------+-----------+-----------|
  | Average  |        16 |        17 |
  |----------+-----------+-----------|
  | Leader 1 |        11 |        12 |
  | Leader 2 |        21 |        22 |
  #+TBLFM: @2$2=vmean(@II$2..@III$2)::@2$3=vmean(@II$3..@III$3)
```

The vector of the two numeric cells in row `Average` of table `TBL_origin`
are referenced in the table formulas of the next tables.

```
  | Use table reference |
  |---------------------|
  |                16.5 |
  #+TBLFM: @2$1=vmean(remote(TBL_origin,@2$2..@2$3))
```

Note that you can not directly assign remote references to table ranges (see the posting
[Re: [Orgmode] remote reference](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2010-01/msg00433.html) in the orgmode mailing list).

A workaround is demonstrated in the following table:

```
  | Refer to averages |
  |-------------------|
  |                16 |
  |                17 |
  #+TBLFM: $1=subscr(remote(TBL_origin,@2$2..@2$3),@#-1)
```

Comment: A note on [remote references in org-table formulas](http://orgmode.org/manual/References.html#References) would be a valuable extension of this answer. Please have a look for the syntax `remote(NAME-OR-ID,REF)` on [the linked page](http://orgmode.org/manual/References.html#index-remote-references-352).

Comment: You are welcome. May I edit your answer and give a usage example for remote references (when I find time)?

Comment: Of course. edit it.

Comment: But how do I call `remote` from elisp? I usually write all my formulas in elisp and cannot mix with `remove(...)` inside an elisp formula. I also tried `(remote ...)`, but no luck.

Comment: Hi, sorry, but those aren't actually radio targets, which are `<<<like this>>>`. Were you saying internal links?