# org-mode: link to tag/target inside a source code block

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, org-link

I'd like to place a link to a tag or target inside a source code block.

```
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
  (use-package evil
    :ensure t
    :config
                      ; enable per default
    (evil-mode t)

                      ; <<evil-bindings>>
    :bind ("C-^" . evil-buffer)  ; Switch to another buffer quickly
#+END_SRC

*** Key bindings

See [[file:::/<<evil-bindings>>/]]
```

Ideally this should jump the to position of `; |<<evil-bindings>>` inside the source block when followed via `C-c C-o`.

I've tried `See [[<<evil-bindings>>]]` before I tried "Method 2" in the answer from user Melioratus in [How to reference source blocks in org text](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/20951). My first try just prompts with `No match - create this as a new heading? (yes or no)` in the minibuffer. The "Method 2" just calls occur as mentioned in the answer. But there's another problem. When going from my first try and editing the link via `C-c C-l` and answering either just `file:::` or `file:::/regexp/` to the `Link:` prompt, it errors out with `org-insert-link: Args out of range: "file:::/<<evil-bindings>>/", 5, 4`. (I then activated     and edited the link manually.)

NB: I haven't configured anything related to org-mode yet (not even `(require 'org)` in my init.el). My emacs and org-mode version:

- GNU Emacs 26.1 (build 2, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.24.5) of 2019-09-23, modified by Debian
- Org mode version 9.1.9 (release_9.1.9-65-g5e4542 @ /usr/share/emacs/26.1/lisp/org/)

Greetings,
 AWG

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> In [literal
>   examples](https://orgmode.org/manual/Literal-Examples.html), Org
>   interprets strings like `(ref:name)` as labels, and use them as
>   targets for special hyperlinks like `[[(name)]]` (...) You can also
>   add a `-r` switch which removes the labels from the source code.

```
See [[(jump)]].

#+begin_src emacs-lisp -r
(let ((x 1))                (ref:jump)
  (print x))
#+end_src
```

Comment: Thank you, works like a charm. :)