# Org Mode - Reference Remote Table From a Different File

Tags: org-mode, org-table

I'm trying to figure out how to reference a cell from a table that is located in a different file. I know I can use `remote(tablename, @1$1)` to reference a remote table within the same file. Is there a similar way to reference a remote table from a different file?

Comment: Usually something like file.org::name should do the trick I think.

Comment: You can check out this question answer http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/19105/how-to-reference-named-table-or-code-block-in-org-mode/19125#19125

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bit tricky and a patch towards accepting the "normal" `file::name` syntax would definitely be appreciated!

Anyway, to refer to a remote file you must use the ID cf. `org-table-get-remote-range`.  I don't know if it was always the case, but IDs seem to be linked to headings now.

### Example with `org-id`

First: `(require 'org-id)`

Create two files in `/tmp`,

```
rasmus:[tmp] $ cat a.org
* foo
#+name: tab-1
| a | 1 |
| b | 2 |
| c | 3 |

rasmus:[tmp] $ cat b.org
| x | 4 |  |
| y | 5 |  |
| z | 6 |  |
```

In `a.org` place the cursor somewhere under `* foo` and do `M-x org-id-get-create`.  This will add an `ID` property to `* foo` and store the location in `~/.emacs.d/.org-id-locations` or similar.  In my case the `ID` is `58efda96-fc03-4c25-91e3-30c987959618`

Now in `b.org` you can use the `ID` as the first argument to your `REMOTE` call.
E.g. to copy the second column in the table in `a.org` to the third column in the table in `b.org` you could use this formula:

```
#+TBLFM: $3=remote(58efda96-fc03-4c25-91e3-30c987959618, @@#$2)
```

So my files now look like this:

```
rasmus:[tmp] $ cat a.org
* foo
:PROPERTIES:
:ID:       58efda96-fc03-4c25-91e3-30c987959618
:END:
#+name: tab-1
| a | 1 |
| b | 2 |
| c | 3 |

rasmus:[tmp] $ cat b.org
| x | 4 | 1 |
| y | 5 | 2 |
| z | 6 | 3 |
#+TBLFM: $3=remote(58efda96-fc03-4c25-91e3-30c987959618, @@#$2)
```

#### Caveats

AFAIR you could once assign an `#+ID:` to a table, but this is gone.  Thus, you might only be able to refer to the first table in a second.  I didn't test this.   I think remote referencing is nice, but it would be great if someone would add standard `org-link-search` support.

### Only at export time

Alternatively, if you only need to update the table in `c.org` at export time you could `#+include` the table in an `noexport` heading and use the standard `#+name` reference.  You'd need to update tables at export time.  There's probably a more elegant way than the one proposed in `c.org` below

```
rasmus:[tmp] $ cat c.org 
| x | 4 |   |
| y | 5 |   |
| z | 6 |   |
#+TBLFM: $3=remote(tab-1, @@#$2)

* misc                                                             :noexport:
#+include: "a.org::tab-1"
#+begin_src emacs-lisp
  (add-hook 'org-export-before-parsing-hook
            (defun rasmus/ox-update-tbl (backend)
              (when (re-search-forward org-table-line-regexp nil t)
                (org-table-recalculate t))))
#+end_src
```