# Reference cells of other tables in org-mode table

Tags: org-mode, org-table, spreadsheet

I have a long document with 10 tables, and I want to to have a summary table at the end of the document. Something like that:

tab1

```
| Nº | Description | Value |
+----+-------------+-------+
|...                       |
+----+-------------+-------+
|    | TOTAL       |   XXX |
```

...

tab10

```
| Nº | Description | Value |
+----+-------------+-------+
|...                       |
+----+-------------+-------+
|    | TOTAL       |   XXX |
```

tab-summary

```
| Description      | Value |
+------------------+-------|
| Total of Table 1 |   XXX |
| Total of Table 2 |   XXX |
| ...                      |
+------------------+-------|
| Grand Total      |   XXX |
```

Is there a way to reference the total of each table, instead of manually coping the results in the summary table?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are looking for [remote table references](http://orgmode.org/manual/References.html#index-remote-references-352):

```
#+TBLNAME: tab1
| Nº  | Description | Value |
|-----+-------------+-------|
|     | TOTAL       |     1 |

...

#+TBLNAME: tab10
| Nº | Description | Value |
|----+-------------+-------|
|    | TOTAL       |     2 |

tab-summary
| Description       | Value |
|-------------------+-------|
| Total of Table 1  |     1 |
| Total of Table 10 |     2 |
|-------------------+-------|
| Grand Total       |     3 |
#+TBLFM: @2$2=remote(tab1,@2$3)::@3$2=remote(tab10,@2$3)::@>$2=vsum(@I$2..@II$2)
```

Note, this question has already an answer there: [How to reference named table or code block in Org-mode](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/19105/how-to-reference-named-table-or-code-block-in-org-mode/19125#19125)

---

You can even generate `tab-summary` automatically.
This is easy if formulas can directly be written into table cells.
The following `ctrl-c-ctrl-c-hook` allows you to install all table formulas from the cells.

```el
(defun org-table-install-formulas ()
  "Install formulas in cells starting with = or := at the bottom of the table as #+TBLFM line.
Do nothing when point is not inside a table."
  (interactive)
  (when (org-table-p)
    (save-excursion
      (goto-char (org-table-begin))
      (org-table-next-field)
      (while (progn
           (org-table-maybe-eval-formula)
           (looking-at "[^|\n]*|\\([[:space:]]*\n[[:space:]]*|\\)?[^|\n]*\\(|\\)"))
    (goto-char (match-beginning 2)))
      ))
  nil)

(add-hook #'org-ctrl-c-ctrl-c-hook #'org-table-install-formulas)
```

The automatic generation of the total-sum table is shown in the following example:

```
#+TBLNAME: tab1
| Nº  | Description | Value |
|-----+-------------+-------|
|     | TOTAL       |     1 |

...

#+TBLNAME: tab2
| Nº | Description | Value |
|----+-------------+-------|
|    | TOTAL       |     2 |

#+TBLNAME: tab3
| Nº | Description | Value |
|----+-------------+-------|
|    | TOTAL       |     3 |


#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :var basename="tbl" start=1 stop=3
(append
 '(("Description" "Value")
   hline)
   (cl-loop for i from start upto stop
        collect (list (format "Total of Table %d" i) (format ":=remote(tab%d,@>$3)" i)))
   '(
     hline
     ("Grand Total" ":=vsum(@I$2..@II$2)")))
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
| Description      | Value               |
|------------------+---------------------|
| Total of Table 1 | :=remote(tab1,@>$3) |
| Total of Table 2 | :=remote(tab2,@>$3) |
| Total of Table 3 | :=remote(tab3,@>$3) |
|------------------+---------------------|
| Grand Total      | :=vsum(@I$2..@II$2) |
```

The example shows the table as it results from the execution of the emacs lisp source block.

If you have installed the above `org-ctrl-c-ctrl-c-hook` place point in the total-sum table and press <kbd>C-c C-c</kbd> you get the following table:

```
| Description      | Value |
|------------------+-------|
| Total of Table 1 |     1 |
| Total of Table 2 |     2 |
| Total of Table 3 |     3 |
|------------------+-------|
| Grand Total      |     6 |
#+TBLFM: @2$2=remote(tab1,@>$3)::@3$2=remote(tab2,@>$3)::@4$2=remote(tab3,@>$3)::@5$2=vsum(@I$2..@II$2)
```

Comment: How can I do this (`remote`) in an elisp formula?